# Get a fixed size slice from array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I need to dynamically retrieve a slice of size 3 from an array (as part of a more complex method):

```
a = %w(a b c d e)
i = 0 # i is an argument, I need [nil, "a", "b"]
a[(i-1)..(i+1)]
=> [] # no luck
a[(i-1), 3]
=> ["e"]
```

I know that when code gets messed up, it's not ruby's fault, is mine. What I'm missing? **Is there a better way to achieve this?**

I need to clarify. What I want is a slice of a given size, *around* a given index, and maping to `nil` if the slice goes beyond offset.

Comment: 'around a given index' ? if `i=0`, what do you expect? ['a', 'b','c'] ?  or ['a', nil, nil]? why your expect is ['e', nil, nil]?

Comment: I think I've been clear enough, given an index(`ì`), I want to return `[a[i-1],a[i],a[i+1]]`, with nil if index goes offset or negative, that's what I mean with 'around'. The problem is that ruby doesnt return nil on negative indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I made it (having to go around ruby indexing negative values):

```
a = %w(a b c d e)
def slice_around(ary, index)
  slice_3 = ->(x){ x == 0 ? [ary.size+1,0,1] : ((x-1)..(x+1)).to_a }
  idxs = slice_3.call(index).map { |i| ary[i] }
end

> slice_around a, 0
=> [nil, "a", "b"]
> slice_around a, 2
=> ["b", "c", "d"]
```

It wont work if a negative index is passed though.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a compact way you can do this. It relies on the fact that indexing beyond an array returns `nil`.

```
>> i = 0; 3.times.map{|j| a[j+i]}
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
>> i = 4; 3.times.map{|j| a[j+i]}
=> ["e", nil, nil]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is [`each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) the method you are looking for? Otherwise try to provide a better example for what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: `each_slice` accepts no starting point and retrieves a smaller slice if `a.size % 3 != 0`, i.e.: (`a.each_slice(3).to_a => [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e"]]`), not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[`Enumerable#each_cons`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) will do the trick:

```
a.each_cons(3){|slice| p slice }
```

output:

```
["a", "b", "c"]
["b", "c", "d"]
["c", "d", "e"]
```